# Spring boot whitelabel 406 error

Tags: spring-boot

I am facing this peculiar issue.

First, I have this as my Controller.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.opus.storeconfigurables.model.Config;
import io.opus.storeconfigurables.service.StoreConfigurablesService;

@RestController
public class StoreConfigurablesController extends BaseEndpoint {
    @Autowired
    private StoreConfigurablesService service;

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/{mode}/{id}", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            headers="Accept=*/*",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @CrossOrigin(origins="*", maxAge=3600)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Config>> listAllUsers(
            @PathVariable("mode") String mode,
            @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        List<Config> configs = service.findAllConfigs(mode, id);
        if(configs.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Config>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Config>>(configs, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and everything worked like a charm. http://localhost:8080/Store/XY29 gave me the response I was expecting in JSON format.

Finally, I added another controller method as this:

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/{mode}/{id}/{rlNumber}", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            headers="Accept=*/*",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @CrossOrigin(origins="*", maxAge=3600)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Config>> listAllPermissions(
            @PathVariable("mode") String mode,
            @PathVariable("id") String id,
            @PathVariable("rlNumber") String rlNumber) {
        List<Config> configs = service.listAllPermissions(mode, id, rlNumber);
        if(configs.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Config>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Config>>(configs, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and my previous request from browser - http://localhost:8080/Store/XY29 - as well as my new request to the new controller method also failed with Whitelabel 406 error. What could be the reason?

I read adding jackson jars to maven pom.xml could solve these issues but no luck there either.

Comment: What is your stacktrace? What if you run the app with --debug? Nothing is staring at me in the face, maybe I am too tired though :/